# Is there a way to append a json object into another json abject in react?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, object, append

How to append one json object into another json object in reactjs?

My json format from the console is below

**Json 1 :**

```
{
 "results": {
             "Action": "Success!"
 },
 "report": {
             "Strategy": "Yes",
             "Plan": "No"
  }
}
```

**Json 2 :**

```
{
     "results": {
                 "Actions": "Failure!"
     },
     "report": {
                 "Idea": "Yep",
                 "Storm": "Nope"
      }
 }
```

**Appended JSON(Desired output format) :**

```
{
     "results": {
                 "Action": "Success!",
                 "Actions": "Failure!"
     },
     "report": {
                 "Strategy": "Yes",
                 "Plan": "No",
                 "Idea": "Yep",
                 "Storm": "Nope"
      }
}
```

Comment: why do you need to create an object with two similar keys? It should be array of object, I guess. The moment someone parses your JSON, the duplicate keys will be merged.

Comment: I have edited my question, I am new to react, that is why I could not convey it exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine two objects

```
const json1 = {
  "results": {
    "Action": "Success!"
  },
  "report": {
    "Strategy": "Yes",
    "Plan": "No"
  }
};

const json2 = {
  "results": {
    "Actions": "Failure!"
  },
  "report": {
    "Idea": "Yep",
    "Storm": "Nope"
  }
};

let res = Object.keys(json1).reduce((a, key) => {
  a[key] = { ...json2[key], ...json1[key] }
  return a
}, {});

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the object and merge it together.

```
const firstJsonObject = JSON.parse(firstJson);
const secondJsonObject = JSON.parse(secondJson);

let res = {};

Object.keys(firstJsonObject).forEach(key => {
  res[key] = { ...firstJson[key], ...secondJsonObject[key] };
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
```

Answer (score 0):

Key can't be duplicate that's why I don't think it's the right way to merge two objects.
If you try to merge last(latest) will replace previous fields(keys).

If you want your output as you mentioned. in that case, you need to change the key field name.

> JavaScript objects cannot have duplicate keys. The keys must all be unique.

Improved

```js
let obj1 = {
 "results": {
      "Action": "Success!"
 },
 "report": {
       "Strategy": "Yes",
       "Plan": "No"
  }
}
let obj2 = {
     "results": {
        "Action": "Failure!"
     },
     "report": {
         "Strategy": "Yep",
         "Plan": "Nope"
      }
 }
 
 let res = {
  results:{...obj1.results, ...obj2.results}, 
  report: {...obj1.report, ...obj2.report}
  };
 console.log(res)
```